# How to perform Case statement inside a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to put 'No record' on the column instead of *NULL* if the datediff function returns a null value.

```
SELECT concat(e.firstname ,e.lastname) as Fullname,c.shiftcode as Shift, cast(c.datecheckinout as date) Date,datename(month, c.datecheckinout) as RecordMonth,c.timein , c.timeout,
CAST( 
    CASE
    WHEN (datediff(HOUR,c.timein,c.timeout)  IS NULL) 
    THEN 'No record'
    END 
    ), FROM tblCheckInOutDetail c  RIGHT JOIN tblEmployee e on e.IdEmployee = c.IdEmployee   WHERE e.IdEmployee = 55
```

So far this code only throws Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'. but I don't know what data type should I put in the CAST parameter , since if there's a record it will show the datetime .

Comment: Tried removing cast and I got but its throwing _Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'No record' to data type int._    ` CASE
 WHEN (datediff(HOUR,c.timein,c.timeout)  IS NULL) 
 THEN 'No record'
 ELSE (datediff(HOUR,c.timein,c.timeout) )
  
 END `

Comment: `ISNULL(datediff(HOUR,c.timein,c.timeout),'n/No Record') as H` is also not working

Comment: Given that you have columns c.timein and c.timeout, can we assume that c.datecheckinout is DATE? If so, why do you cast it? If not, why do you NOT use the date datatype for that column? You should be supplying good aliases for your expressions used as columns. And please add any useful information to your original post and not as columns.

Comment: Hi , @smor . yes c.datecheckinout is a datetime I wanted to get only the date format. Yes, thank you for the reminder. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly answering question (though I don't understand why you need a [`CASE` expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) if you have working versions of the query), you can easily translate this to a `CASE` expression:

```
ISNULL(CAST(datediff(HOUR,c.timein,c.timeout) as varchar),'No Record')
```

`ISNULL` really is just nice, convenient shorthand for `CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN a ELSE b END`, so:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, c.timein, c.timeout) IS NOT NULL
  THEN CAST(datediff(HOUR,c.timein,c.timeout) as varchar(11))
  ELSE 'No Record' END
```

As you can see, a downside is that if you really really really want a `CASE` expression, you have to repeat at least the `DATEDIFF` to cover both the case where the outer row doesn't exist and the case where the outer row exists but one of the values is `NULL`.

Also note that you should [always specify a length for variable types like `varchar`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), even in cases where you think you're safe with the default.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the number value to a string.  For this, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT concat(e.firstname ,e.lastname) as Fullname,c.shiftcode as Shift, cast(c.datecheckinout as date) Date,datename(month, c.datecheckinout) as RecordMonth,c.timein , c.timeout,
       COALESCE(CAST(datediff(HOUR, c.timein, c.timeout) AS VARCHAR(255)), 'No record')
FROM tblEmployee e LEFT JOIN
     tblCheckInOutDetail c 
     ON e.IdEmployee = c.IdEmployee
WHERE e.IdEmployee = 55;
```

Note:  I switched the `RIGHT JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.  They are equivalent logically.  But most people find it much easier to follow the logic of the `LEFT JOIN`, because the table that defines the rows is the first table being read in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks, this is also another working option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct option or usage.

but this works for me :

```
ISNULL(CAST(datediff(HOUR,c.timein,c.timeout) as varchar),'No Record')
```

But can you guys show me how to do this using case expression?

Comment: Please [don't cast as `varchar` without specifying the length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), even if you know you don't need it. Also, [`CASE` is an expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression), not a statement, the semantics here can be really important. Finally, if you have multiple versions of the query that are working, why do you need one with a `CASE` expression so badly?

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I was thinking about displaying the current time computation from the c.timein,  while there's no record for the column c.timeout. I hope you understand.